# Spark error: Neither previous window has value for key, nor new values found

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm running a Spark Streaming application that uses reduceByKeyAndWindow(). The window interval is 2 hours, while the slide interval is 1 hour. I have a JavaPairRDD in which both keys and values are strings. Each time the reduceByKeyAndWindow() function is called, it uses appendString() and removeString() functions below to incrementally build a windowed stream of data:

```
Function2<String, String, String> appendString = new Function2<String, String, String>() {
  @Override
  public String call(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1 + s2;
  }
};

Function2<String, String, String> removeString = new Function2<String, String, String>() {
  @Override
  public String call(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.replace(s2, "");
  }
};
```

filterEmptyRecords() removes keys that eventually won't contain any value:

```
Function<scala.Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean> filterEmptyRecords = new Function<scala.Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean>() {
  @Override
  public Boolean call(scala.Tuple2<String, String> t) {
    return (!t._2().isEmpty());
  }
};
```

The windowed operation is then:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> cdr_kv = cdr_filtered.reduceByKeyAndWindow(appendString, removeString, Durations.seconds(WINDOW_DURATION), Durations.seconds(SLIDE_DURATION), PARTITIONS, filterEmptyRecords);
```

After a few hours of operation, this function raises the following exception:
"Neither previous window has value for key, nor new values found. Are you sure your key class hashes consistently?"

I've found this post from 2013: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spark-users/9OM1YvWzwgE/PhFgdSTP2OQJ
which however doesn't solve my problem. I'm using String to represent keys, which I'm pretty sure hash consistently.

Any clue why this happens and possible suggestions to fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT

I'm using Spark Streaming 1.6.1. I read data from a file:

```
JavaDStream<String> file_orig = jssc.textFileStream(MY_DIR).repartition(PARTITIONS);
```

Then, I parse the strings read from the file in order to create a PairRDD of the form

```
Key: 0000; Value: aaa|bbb|ccc
Key: 0001; Value: ddd|eee|fff
...
```

The key is a number, but is represented as String. Some pairs may have null values, so they are filtered out.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> file_filtered = file_orig.mapToPair(parserFunc)
                                                       .filter(new Function<scala.Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean>() {
                                                         @Override
                                                         public Boolean call(scala.Tuple2<String, String> t) {
                                                           return (!t._2().contains("null"));
                                                         }
                                                       });
```

After this, I apply the windowed operation described above (see code) and later on I join the windowed stream with another JavaPairRDD. The problem I described above happens during the windowed operation, when old data cached in previous batches is removed. The window size is 2 hours, while the slide interval is 1 hour.

Comment: Any help with this?

Comment: What is your Key and Value like? Can you give us an example? How do you create your pairRDD?

Comment: The JavaPairRDD is created through a mapToPair operation after ingesting data from a text file. See the EDIT section for further details and additional code snippets.

Comment: Thanks. The _after few hours operation_ means that initially it does work, correct?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly for 2 hours (window size), then when the window slides it gives me problems. That's the moment in which some of the old keys/values are removed from the PairRDD.

Comment: Apologies for my lateness: at what line precisely does the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I apologise for my lateness. From the documentation and my cerebral capacity I see that: [The second argument](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) you are using is a ["inverse reduce function"](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transform-operation), which can be applied only to reversible functions.
Since it is applied only to elements that leave the window, are you sure that anything IS indeed leaving the window?
Just as an alternate approach to check: map and filter the results of a simple reduceByKeyAndWindow(f,dur,slide,partitions) function

Comment: Thank for the answer, give me some time to go over this